# Open a fragment of an activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, start-activity

Hi All I want to open the "Text-To-Speech output" fragment of Settings from my application. I think first I need to open the settings activity and then its fragment. I tried setting the `ComponentName` but it was unable to locate the activity.

Should I use `FragmentManager`; I couldn't find anything specific to my needs. Can somebody give me some link which might explain it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Intent ttsSettings = new Intent("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
ttsSettings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(ttsSettings);
```

Comment: I wish I could buy a beer for you..thanks buddy..:)
P.S. I have a release today and I was involved in other task also. And it will open up at a shortcut in Launcher.

Comment: If you are using a sections pager adapter please see my answer here in detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/55722092/3904109

Comment: This used to work for me perfectly 10 years ago. Now, after I imported my project from Eclipse/ADT to Android Studio (2021.3.1.17), I am getting: *"Class referenced in the manifest, com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS , was not found in the project or the libraries"*. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 16):

You are right, First You need to start the Activity than set the current Fragment in FragmentPager / Manager... Their is no such way to start some foreign fragment from your Activity that would be dangerous see that will lead to zombie fragments floating around the App (or May be I am not aware of that..)

1. You call the Activity Intent with some parameter for the Fragment name, you want to start i.e. interger, boolean etc...

   ```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("fragmentNumber",1); //for example    
     startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. You check the passed value inside OnCreate of the Second Acitivty and set the desired fragment on top.. inside OnCreate

   ```
    if(getIntent().getIntExtra("fragmentNumber",0)==1){
      //set the desired fragment as current fragment to fragment pager
     }
   ```

However, I am not getting the problem `"It was unable to locate the activity."` Have you entered the Activity in manifest file than what was the problem you were facing?  Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Which flag you want to use with the Intent highly depends upon your dealing with Activity in your Activity Stack.. For the best suitable flag for your requirement see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html...