# How to start a fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to start a fragment from B activity but the fragment is in main activity. If I use FragmentTransaction, but it gives error "No view found for ID for fragment"

Code

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.layoutContent, frag);
ft.commit();
```

Error

> No view found for id 0x7f0e00be (com.company.app:id/layoutContent) for fragment PlaylistFrag{5764566 #0 id=0x7f0e00be}

Comment: Use inteface or local broadcast and replace fragment in its callback

Comment: Id 0x7f0e00be is layoutContent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761812/change-viewpager-fragment-by-a-buttonclick/16770088#16770088

Comment: you are getting error because of the you have not make FrameContainer  id as layoutContent

Comment: I am using it as menu item. But one of my activity is not in nav item. So when i switch to fragment from that activity, it gives error.

Comment: If you are using a sections pager adapter please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55722092/3904109 it will help you

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, You want to start a fragment in an Activity from another Activity. 
This is what I do to get Around that.

1. From the current Activity, I would start the other Activity on Click

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent (ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
   intent.putExtra("EXTRA", "openFragment");
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. In the destination Activity, listen for intent extras and start action.

   ```
   switch (getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA")){ 
       case "openFragment":
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.replacableLayout, new FragmentActivityB()).commit();
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment Activity B");
           break;
   }
   ```

It works for me...

Comment: But, R.id.replacableLayout is only ActivityA not in ActivityB

Answer (score 0):

this will fire an exception as `getSupportFragmentManager()` is a function with the Activity you work on it so when you use `ft.replace(R.id.layoutContent, frag);` will look for layoutContent on current activity and will not found

i don't how u want to

Solution ==> - use Event Bus or Rxjava :) or may use a n interface with setter and getter and check it in another activity or use static variable to check the fragment you want to replaced to :)

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your onClick

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

and add onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use a sections pager adapter to achieve this as in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55722092/3904109

Answer (score -1):

Make Layout like below in MainActivity.java and its layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_add_workout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nujster.activity.AddWorkoutActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_workout_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Then**, in main activity write below code to call fragment

```
public class AddWorkoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_workout);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.add_workout_fragment, new LevelFragment(), "levels").addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("levels") != null) {
            LevelFragment levelFragment = (LevelFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("levels");
            if (levelFragment.isVisible()){
               finish();
            } else{
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ganesh Sumb What is your exact problem I didn't get it, please elaborate it.

Answer (score -1):

You can load same fragment in different activities.

Usually Fragment loads in Activity container.

Activity-1 layout have a container say R.id.layoutContent
Activity-2 layout also should have a container R.id.xxx

```
ft.replace(R.id.layoutContent[Container where fragment loads], frag);
```

May be Activity-2 do not have id of container

Comment: Activity 2 doesn't have the container ID. It isn't "maybe" it doesn't