# how to open fragment from another activity android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

i am trying to use startactivityfromfragment()
i didnt find sumthing usefull for me to be a good example 
until now i was able to move data(string of web url) from fragment to fragment
now its a diffrent story.. i think i need to use startactivityfromfragment()..
but dont know how

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("WEB","someweb.com");
                MultiFragment multiFragment = new MultiFragment();
                multiFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MultiFragment.class);
                startActivityFromFragment(MainActivity.class,intent1,"WEB");
```

Comment: You can simply use intent to start an activity from a fragment.

Comment: i can easily use the intent to the main activity - true.. but i want to get inside a fragment that is a part of MainActivity from - Another activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
Put this code in current fragment, from where you want to open an activity.

```
 Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Multifragment.class);
    i.putExtra("key","value");
    getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

In the next activity which contains fragment, put these:

```
String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key",value);
YourFragmentClass ob=new YourFragmentClass();
ob.setArguments(bundle);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_container_layout,ob).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Then, In YouFragmentClass:

```
Bundle=getArguments();
if(bundle!=null}
String value=bundle.getString("key");
```

Comment: MaiinActivity' is not an enclosing class .. so its an error on it.. evryithing is an error

Comment: thank you.. it took me a while to understand you- it worked for me from another activity to another activity that contains a fragment - rock on!

Comment: If you are using a sections pager adapter please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55722092/3904109

Answer (score 0):

Use your Activity name as second parameter in which the your MultiFragment exist

```
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityName.class);
                       putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
```

Comment: yeah but i need to get inside a specific fragment inside the activity

Comment: multifragment.class i a fragment for webview... i tried call it as a fragment but no sucess

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

For sending data from activity to another activity's fragment call a normal intent with bundle value, In another activity check on getIntent() and call a method from that fragment

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("web_url", "url");
startActivity(intent);
```

and call from another activity

```
String webUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("web_url");
Fragment newFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_tab);
newFragment.openWeb(webUrl);
```

**Method 2**
In second activity make a static variable and save the data from getIntent() and in fragment use that variable.

**Mehtod 3**

```
    interface FragmentListner{
    void openFragment(String url);
}
```

Activity A :

```
    FragmentListner frag = new FragmentListner();
    frag.openFragment("Url");
```

Activity B:

```
class B implements FragmentListner{

void openFragment(String url){
//Open Fragment here
}
```

Comment: yes but its a fragment in another activity - not activity to an activity - do you know how to use this? startactivityfromfragment()

Comment: If you want to open an activity from fragment than normally change 'this' to getActivity() and use getActivirty().startActivity(intent);

Comment: Make an interface in another activity initialize there and call a function from that interface and Implement in that activity in which u want to open fragment on that method

Comment: the problem is - i need it to be open only if i come from this acticity - take me to the Multifragment.. all other just take me to MainFragment

Answer (score 0):

I think:

In an activity that doesn't contain fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                    intent.putExtra("something", "yep");
                    startActivity(intent);
```

And, in the next activity which contains fragment:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String op = intent.getStringExtra("something");
if (op != null){
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,
         new YourFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```